# Textos com efeito indesejado no Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Por que meu texto aparece com outro em baixo dele depois que adiciono a biblioteca do Bootstrap na página? (Observe o Copyright e o texto do topo)

[image: Observe o Copyright e o texto do topo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o *Bootstrap* possui estilos **CSS próprios** para tags `<p>`, `<h6>`, etc.

Se você inspecionar o estilo do elemento, verá que o Bootstrap adiciona vários estilos a essas tags. E isso faz com que fique um pouco "estranho" em sua aplicação.

Você pode resolver isso de duas principais formas:

**1 (recomendado)** - No CSS de seu projeto, sobrescreva o estilo da tag em questão (provavelmente `<hx>`, onde x é o valor do header (1, 2...)) com o estilo que você quiser.

**2** - Alterar o estilo do próprio código do bootstrap para o estilo que você quer.

Espero ter ajudado :)

Atenciosamente,

Comment: Olá, já havia tentado a primeira opção mas sem sucesso. Então fiz de novo, só que dessa vez alterando a propriedade "text-shadow: none;" e funcionou. Obrigado!